# SCP between two different servers with two different ports

Tags: scp, remote

The thing is, you can specify a port to SCP, and you can transfer stuff from a remote host to another.

If both hosts use different ports on SSH (i.e. 2203 and 2541), how can I specify these ports to the SCP command?

I know I can do

```
scp -P <port> host1:/file host2:/file
```

But that port will apply to **both** hosts.

So... how can I specify two different ports for the two different hosts?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/153960/scp-with-two-different-ports

Comment: The simplest way would be to add an entry for each host in `~/.ssh/config` specifying each host's specific port.

Comment: @kyngo - what OS are you on, what's your version of scp?

Comment: @tink Linux, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS now (back then it was 16.04). The latest version was installed at the moment, can't remember.

Answer (score -1):

After tink's comment: I think this may not apply to Linux, but to BSD systems:

The source and target can be specified as a URI in the form scp://[user@]host[:port][/path]

so you can run:

```
scp scp://user1@host1:port1/path/to/file1 scp://user2@host2:port2/path/to/file2
```

And to copy between two remote hosts through the local host add "-3":

```
scp -3 scp://user1@host1:port1/path/to/file1 scp://user2@host2:port2/path/to/file2
```

Comment: `scp`  as shipped with with Ubuntu 16.04  ` 1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.7` doesn't understand this syntax. What OS, which version of ssh/scp are you using?

Comment: I tested with Suse and it does not work as well. This may be limited to BSD systems only.